# How do I open a file in assembler and print the content of it?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, file-descriptor

I want to open a file in assembly. The file is called `test.txt`. I tried to open the file with `open`, and then the content is read into `content`. At last, I want to output the content with `write`, however I get a segfault. When I look at strace:

```
execve("./sh", ["./sh"], 0x7fffffffe980 /* 34 vars */) = 0
open("test.txt", O_WRONLY)              = 3
read(3, 0x402000, 48)                   = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
write(1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48) = 48
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x30} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Some `0`'s are outputted. That means that this address contains nothing, and the read must have failed. Can someone help?
Here is the code:

```
section .bss
    content: resb 0x30

section .text
global start
_start:
    push rax
    mov rbx, 0x7478742e74736574 ; test.txt
    push qword rbx
    mov rdi, rsp
    push 0x1
    pop rsi
    xor rdx, rdx
    mov al, 0x2
    syscall
    
    push rax
    pop rdi
    mov rsi, content
    mov dl, 0x30
    xor rax, rax
    syscall
    
    push 0x1
    pop rdi
    mov rsi, content
    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 0x1
    syscall

    mov al, 0x3c
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Comment: As strace shows, you have opened it `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: @Jester yes, because I want to read the contents of the file, not write anything to it

Comment: `O_WRONLY` is **write only**. You want `O_RDONLY`.

Comment: @Jester thank you. The number for the mode ```O_RDONLY``` is 0, right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. Check what strace says.

Comment: or maybe you want O_RDWR

Comment: Why would you write `push 1; pop rsi` and `push rax; pop rdi` instead of simply `mov esi, 1` and `mov edi, eax`?

Comment: You shouldn’t use `mov rsi, content` but instead use `lea rsi, [rel content]` which will work even if your code is loaded outside the low   31 bits of address space. (I recommend using `default rel` so you don’t have to put it on every memory reference.)

Comment: @prl because I want to avoid null bytes

Comment: A 64-bit absolute address will include `00` bytes on x86-64.  Also, if avoiding `00` bytes is relevant (e.g. for shellcode), you can't use a separate section like `.bss` anyway.  Use stack space, like `sub rsp, 0x30` / `mov rsi, rsp`